# How can I tell if the image returned from didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo was from the camera or the photoalbum?

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

I have a view controller that needs to be able to choose a picture from the photo album and also from the camera. I can only have 1 delegate method for didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo and while I can tell if it's an image, I can't seem to tell if it's from the album or from the camera (and I need to save it in the album first). Is there anything in the info that can help me distinguish from the two?

Thanks...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Because the `UIImagePickerController` is passed to the method, all you have to do is:

```m
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
  if ([picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
    // Do something with an image from the camera
  } else {
    // Do something with an image from another source
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

In Swift3:

```m
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    if picker.sourceType == .camera {
      // Do something with an image from the camera
    }
    else {
      // Do something with an image from another source
    }

  }
```

Comment: In Swift 3.0, it's now `picker.sourceType == .camera`, since `.Camera` has been replaced by `.camera`. The other values are `.photoLibrary` and  `.savedPhotosAlbum`. HTH