# iOS UIImagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo Vs editingInfo

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to create an app, which can take photos from camera and can also pic images from gallery.

But the problem I am having is,

When I chose to take picture from Camera it works fine, I'm using

```
    - (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) pickerr didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info;
```

But when I go for the gallery to pic an images, using

```
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)pickerr didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *) image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo;
```

the above method is executed and the pic I have selected is saved again.

If I comment the first method then I am able to show the selected image in UIImageView.

What should be changed, so that both can work perfectly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:` is **Deprecated in iOS 3.0**

try this method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`

Comment: thanks but solved the problem from using the [How can i tell ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155311/how-can-i-tell-if-the-image-returned-from-didfinishpickingmediawithinfo-was-from?rq=1)

Comment: And yes, MediaWithInfo has solved the problem, with little help from above link.